# Testing that an expression resolves to an integer

Tags: simplifying-expressions

As shown in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wYz7hoKBp1Y), the expression

$$4 \sqrt{4 - 2 \sqrt{3}} + \sqrt{97 - 56 \sqrt{3}}$$

is in fact an integer.

One way to check is:

```
FullSimplify[4 Sqrt[4 - 2 Sqrt[3]] + Sqrt[97 - 56 Sqrt[3]]]
```

which resolves to $3$, and

```
IntegerQ@FullSimplify[4 Sqrt[4 - 2 Sqrt[3]] + Sqrt[97 - 56 Sqrt[3]]]
```

resolves to `True`.  Great.

But the direct computation:

```
IntegerQ[4 Sqrt[4 - 2 Sqrt[3]] + Sqrt[97 - 56 Sqrt[3]]]
```

gives `False`.

Why doesn't *Mathematica* yield `True` to the direct computation?  After all, it resolves other such expressions, such as this trivial example:

```
IntegerQ[Sqrt[5]^2]
```

(* True *)

Comment: [`RootReduce`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RootReduce.html) can do this simplification and is a pretty powerful tool all-around.

Comment: @Roman:  Ahh yes... very helpful.  Thanks.  But still... why would *Mathematica* give `False` to the direct approach?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork  Simplification usually does not happen automatically.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The result of

```
IntegerQ[4 Sqrt[4 - 2 Sqrt[3]] + Sqrt[97 - 56 Sqrt[3]]]
```

> `False`

is as designed. Let us look in the documentation to `IntegerQ`, namely, in the Details section

> IntegerQ[expr] returns False unless expr is manifestly an integer (i.e. has head Integer).

Let us check

```
Head[4 Sqrt[4 - 2 Sqrt[3]] + Sqrt[97 - 56 Sqrt[3]]]
```

> `Plus`